# error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant in Serial communication ATmega32

Tags: c, serial-communication, baud-rate, atmega32

I am trying to connect a Bluetooth module through serial communication. But the error which is " error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before numeric constant" occurred on the line where I defined the baud rate. can not find where the error is. Help would be appreciated, thanks!

```
#define BAUD_RATE 9600
#define BAUD_PreS (((F_CPU / (BAUD_RATE * 16UL))) - 1)

void USART_init(long BAUD_RATE){

       UCSRB |= (1 << RXEN ) | (1 << TXEN ) ;                   
       UCSRC |= (1 << URSEL) | (1 << UCSZ0) | (1 << UCSZ1) ;
       UBRRH  = (BAUD_PreS >> 8);
       UBRRL  = BAUD_PreS;
}
```

Comment: You can't use `BAUD_RATE` as a function argument, since it's a macro that expands into a number. You've written the equivalent of `void USART_init(long 9600)`

Comment: With the defines shown this line `void USART_init(long BAUD_RATE)` becomes `void USART_init(long 9600)` after preprocessing. You should choose a different name for the argument or remove it completely since you are not using it.

Comment: `BAUD_RATE` shouldn't be a macro if you want to use it as the function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

The precompiler will replace `BAUD_RATE` with `9600`, so this:

```
#define BAUD_RATE 9600
void USART_init(long BAUD_RATE){
```

becomes

```
#define BAUD_RATE 9600
void USART_init(long 9600){
//              ^^^^^^^^^
```

So, you need to give the variable in `USART_init` a different name - but, since it's not even used in the function, just remove it:

```
void USART_init(){
```

Comment: Actually I think he needs to get rid of the macro, so `BAUD_PreS` will use the function parameter as intended.

Comment: @Barmar Indeed. I added a comment

Comment: No, that's not what I meant. They need to get rid of `#define BAUD_RATE 9600`

Comment: @Barmar `BAUD_PreS` is defined using `BAUD_RATE`

Comment: No it isn't. Remember, it's just a macro, it expands into an expression that uses that variable.

Comment: @Barmar Sure, but you could either take it as a parameter as you suggest, or let it be a macro. `BAUD_PreS` will use `9600` after expansion.

Comment: I assume that the function is supposed to initialize to the requested baud rate, not a hard-coded default.

Comment: @Barmar Could be. It'd certainly make it more flexible, but if someone writes `#define BAUD_RATE 9600` I expect that hardcoding to be deliberate - then again, the function signature suggests that it should be a runtime choice. Hard to guess.

Comment: I also think `USART_init(long BAUD_RATE)` is deliberate. One of them is wrong.

Comment: @Barmar Absolute agreement.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the line

```
#define BAUD_RATE 9600
```

It looks like you want `BAUD_PreS` to expand into something that depends on the argument to `USART_init()`. So you shouldn't define that as a macro, it needs to get the value that was passed as the argument to the function.

Usually this type of macro is written as a function-style macro.

```
#define BAUD_PreS(r) (((F_CPU / ((r) * 16UL))) - 1)
```

Then you would use it as:

```
       UBRRH  = (BAUD_PreS(BAUD_RATE) >> 8);
       UBRRL  = BAUD_PreS(BAUD_RATE);
```

Comment: Yes, I think this is the better choice if the baud rate isn't supposed to be hardcoded to `9600`.